# 3d arrays in c-programming

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a [2][3][2]={{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}},{{5,8},{9,10},{11,12}}};

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",a[1]-a[0],a[1][0]-a[0][0],a[1][0][0]-a[0][0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `3 6 4`. Can anyone explain to me the reason for this? How come `a[1]-a[0]=3` and `a[1][0]-a[0][0]=6` and how `a[]` and `a[][]` interprets in a 3-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you understand how an array like yours is laid out in memory:

```
+------------+   Low address    +---------+   Low address    +------+
| a[0][0][0] |                  | a[0][0] |                  | a[0] |
| a[0][0][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
| a[0][1][0] |                  | a[0][1] |                  |      |
| a[0][1][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
| a[0][2][0] |                  | a[0][2] |                  |      |
| a[0][2][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
| a[1][0][0] |                  | a[1][0] |                  | a[1] |
| a[1][0][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
| a[1][1][0] |                  | a[1][1] |                  |      |
| a[1][1][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
| a[1][2][0] |                  | a[1][2] |                  |      |
| a[1][2][1] |                  |         |                  |      |
+------------+   High address   +---------+   High address   +------+
```

Then it helps to know that the difference you get is in *multiples of the type*. So for `a[0]` and `a[1]` the type is `int[3][2]` and there are three of those multiples between `a[0]` and `a[1]`.

Same for `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]`, the type is `int[2]`, and the difference is six `int[2]` units between `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]`.

---

To elaborate a little: Between `a[0]` and `a[1]` you have `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]` and `a[0][2]`. Three entries.

Between `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` you have `a[0][0][0]`, `a[0][0][1]`, `a[0][1][0]`, `a[0][1][1]`, `a[0][2][0]` and`a[0][2][1]`. Six entries.

Comment: please elaborate this

Comment: @BakulMittal a[0] and a[0][0] are pointers, so when you substract them with a[1] and a[1][0], the result is difference between two memory locations. a[0][0][0] and a[1][0][0] are values in the array, so when you substract them, you get difference between two values.

Comment: can you please explain how compiler interpret it through addressing

Comment: @BakulMittal Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So `a[0]` decays to `&a[0][0]`. What the compiler is doing is subtracting the pointers for `&a[0][0]` from `&a[1][0]`, and dividing that difference with the size of the type (which is `int[3][2]`).

Comment: @ sir Joachim Pileborg the address int [3][2]=(3*2+2)*4 bytes and int[2]= 2*4 bytes so how its interpreted

Answer (score 0):

At the point of address, a[1] and a[1][0] are the same value. And a[0] and a[0][0] are same value.

But the types are different.

a[1][0] and a[0][0] are int *, from a[0][0] to a[1][0], there are 6 int.

And from a[1] to a[0], there are 3 {x, y}.

a[1][0][0] and a[0][0][0] are int, a[1][0][0]-a[0][0][0] = 5 - 1 = 4.

Comment: can u please elaborate it

Comment: The Add and subtract of pointers is multiple of types. For example, int *a =   100; int *b = 0; a - b = 25, 25 * sizeof(int)

Answer (score 0):

In C, a multi-dimensional array is conceptually an array whose elements are also arrays. So if you do:

int array[2][3]; Conceptually you end up with:

```
array[0] => [0, 1, 2]
array[1] => [0, 1, 2]
```

int array[2][3][2]; ...will give you a structure like:

```
array[0] => [0] => [1, 2]
            [1] => [3, 4]
            [2] => [5, 6]
array[1] => [0] => [5, 8]
            [1] => [9, 10]
            [2] => [11, 12]
```

a[1]-a[0]  => will give difference you get is type of unit. a[0] and a[1] is int and there are three unit between them.similarly for the second part

a[1][0]-a[0][0]=6

number of combination for between a[0][0] and a[1][0] is 6.